# How to specify Angular 4 environment when running e2e protractor tests?

Tags: angular, protractor

I have prepush script which runs:

```
npm test && npm run ng e2e
```

In the Angular environment.ts I have this:

```
redirectUri: 'http://localhost:4300/dashboard'
```

That is for Auth0.

Problem is that ng test runs on the 49152 port, so when running prepush script, which is executed before git push, redirecting url is wrong.

How can I solve this specifically for Angular 4? I can't change port for ng tests, it has to stay as it is.

I also tried using --environment parameter on ng test to specify another environment with 49152 port but it's ignored.

Comment: Can you overwrite it in the protractor onPrepare in the config file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. My scripts were wrong.

I had e2e script which was running just this:

```
protractor
```

prepush was calling:

```
npm test && npm run ng e2e
```

Now, I changed e2e script to:

```
ng e2e -e testing
```

And prepush to:

```
npm test && npm run e2e
```

And it works, environment is working as it should.